# False Mirrors. can you help me to solve?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Here is the [problem](http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1152)

> BFG-9000 destroys three adjacent balconies per one shoot. (N-th balcony is adjacent to
>       the first one). After the shoot the survival monsters inflict damage to Leonid 
>       (main hero of the novel) — one unit per monster. Further follows new shoot and so on
>       until all monsters 
>       will perish. It is required to define the minimum amount of damage,
>       which can take Leonid.

For example :

```
N = 8
A[] = 4 5 6 5 4 5 6 5

answer : 33
4 * * * 4 5 6 5 - 24
4 * * * * * * 5 - 9
* * * * * * * * - 0
```

Can you help me to solve this problem? What is the complexity?

Comment: Oh dang, I just spent 10 minutes writing a solution and just realized that my approach doesn't always work :-(

Answer (score 2):

Problem can be solved with DP.

After first shot problem will not be circular anymore. Damage of monsters that left after attack can be calculated with DP. Lets `NB` is number of balconies.

Define `D[n,m]` for `n<=m` or `m+4<=n`as damage of monsters left on balconies `b`, `n<=b<=m` or `m<=b<=n`.

```
If n <= m < n+3 than D[n,m] = sum A[i] for n<=i<=m.
If m >= n+3 than D[n,m] =
   min{ 2*D[n,i-1] + D[i,i+2] + 2*D[i+3,m] } for i in {n,...,m}.
If m < n than D[n,m] =
   min{ 2*D[n,i-1] + D[i,i+2] + 2*D[i+3,m] } for i in {n,...,NB} U {1,...,m}.
```

Result is `min{ D[i+3,NB+i-1] for i in {1,...,NB-2} }`.

In third case and result indices are modulo NB.

This approach has complexity `O(n^3)`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the constraints of the problem are such that you can just brute force it .  Basically

```
def go(hit):
    res = 999 
    #base case, check if all items in hit are true.
    for i in range(len(hit)):
        if not hit[i]:
             newhit = [x for x in hit]
             newhit[i] = newhit[i-1] = newhit[(i+1)%len(hit)] = True; 
             damage = 0;
             for j in range(len(hit)):
                  if not newhit[j]:
                     damage+=hit[j]
             res = min(res, go(newhit)+damage)
```

You can also implement hit as a bit map and then memoize it to speed up the function.

Comment: I don't know python. can you tell me mean of this code `newhit = [x for x in hit]` ?

Comment: @Elmi - that just copies the array. This is better implemented as a bitset or integer whose binary value marks the 'hit' balconies

Comment: @spinnig_place I don't understand your code can you write in C++ or C please?

Comment: It was meant more as pseudo-code.  I won't write it for you, but the idea is simply to create a recursive function that takes in a set of bits representing what balconies are gone.  The function then considers any existing balcony and takes it down along with the 2 adjancent balconies and then recurses.   If you have specific questions id be happy to answer