# Facebook interview: find out the order that gives max sum by selecting boxes with number in a ring, when the two next to it is destroyed

Tags: facebook, dynamic-programming

Didn't find any similar question about this.
This is a final round Facebook question:

You are given a ring of boxes. Each box has a non-negative number on it, can be duplicate.

Write a function/algorithm that will tell you the order at which you select the boxes, that will give you the max sum.

The catch is, if you select a box, it is taken off the ring, and so are the two boxes next to it (to the right and the left of the one you selected).

so if I have a ring of
{10 3 8 12}

If I select 12,  8 and 10 will be destroyed and you are left with 3.

The max will be selecting 8 first then 10, or 10 first then 8.

I tried re-assign the boxes their value by take its own value and then subtracts the two next to is as the cost.

So the old ring is {10 3 8 12}

the new ring is {-5, -15, -7, -6}, and I will pick the highest.

However, this definitely doesn't work if you have { 10, 19, 10, 0}, you should take the two 10s, but the algorithm will take the 19 and 0.

Help please?

It is most likely dynamic programming, but I don't know how.

The ring can be any size.

Comment: It was done already..., and this was not my interview :)

Comment: I said it was a Facebook final round interview question, never said it was my. : )

Comment: Looks similar to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048025/problem-false-mirrors-can-you-help-me-to-solve).

Comment: That question is different because it was counting what is the min left. This problem, if you want to have the min left after a selection, then you will pick the greatest trio. However, only the middle one is going to be added to the sum, and the two on the side are cost, and it will be high cost, if we pick the largest trio.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some python that solves the problem:

```py
def sublist(i,l):
    if i == 0:
        return l[2:-1]
    elif i == len(l)-1:
        return l[1:-2]
    else:
        return l[0:i-1] + l[i+2:]

def val(l):
    if len(l) <= 3:
        return max(l)
    else:
        return max([v+val(m) for v,m in [(l[u],sublist(u,l)) for u in range(len(l))]])

def print_indices(l):
    print("Total:",val(l))
    while l:
        vals = [v+val(m) for v,m in [(l[u],sublist(u,l)) for u in range(len(l)) if sublist(u,l)]]
        if vals:
            i = vals.index(max(vals))
        else:
            i = l.index(max(l))
        print('choice:',l[i],'index:',i,'new list:',sublist(i,l))
        l = sublist(i,l)

print_indices([10,3,8,12])
print_indices([10,19,10,0])
```

**Output:**

> Total: 18
>   choice: 10 index: 0 new list: [8]
>   choice: 8 index: 0 new list: []
>
> Total: 20
>   choice: 10 index: 0 new list: [10]
>   choice: 10 index: 0 new list: []

No doubt it could be optimized a bit.  The key bit is `val()`, which calculates the total value of a given ring.  The rest is just bookkeeping.

Comment: can you explain the logic behind in words , so that we dont have to read the code and spend time on making it out.

Comment: @Peter It's been awhile, but the gist is that it recursively calculates the expected value of every possible series of choices.